# Cannot complete the function with CDOEX and Exchange 2000

Tags: activex, appointment, exchange-server-2003

I am trying to create an appointment using CDOEX in Exchange 2000. The code snippet is from msdn and is VB6.

When I reach this line: ".DataSource.SaveToContainer iMbx.Calendar, Conn" I am getting error "cannot complete the function (800703eb)"

Any help will be appreciated!

```
Function CreateAppointment(StartTime As Date, _
                            EndTime As Date, _
                            Subject As String, _
                            Location As String, _
                            TextBody As String, _
                            iMbx As IMailbox) As Appointment

' Reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library
' Reference to Microsoft CDO for Exchange 2000 Library

    Dim iAppt       As New Appointment
    Dim Conn        As New ADODB.Connection
    Conn.Provider = "ExOLEDB.DataSource"

    'Set the appointment properties
    With iAppt
        .StartTime = StartTime
        .EndTime = EndTime
        .Subject = Subject
        .Location = Location
        .TextBody = TextBody
        'Save the appointment
        Conn.Open iMbx.BaseFolder
        .DataSource.SaveToContainer iMbx.Calendar, Conn
    End With

    Set CreateAppointment = iAppt
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem and solution, so here it is in case somebody needs it: [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310440)
Also, I have found examples that saved my life: [link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=4afe3504-c209-4a73-ac5d-ff2a4a3b48b7&displaylang=en)